# how to handle a kafka topic when the listener has been removed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I had a kafka consumer for a specific topic. Because of reasons I changed the consumer. Instead of consuming the message now I have a kafka-stream which handles the topic and produces new messages to different topics. This works fine.

My problem is I looked at the kafka messages with an UI and found out that kafka now thinks the old consumer is thousands of messages behind. I would like to tell kafka that this consumer now is gone or should I just ignore this? I cannot remove the complete consumer group because I have some consumers with the same group on other topics.

Comment: Consumer groups are delete automatically after a configurable amount of time. It's a broker config `offsets.retention.minutes`. -- Or you delete explicitly as proposed by @groo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool and specify the group and topic to be deleted. It has a delete option.

`bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group my-group --topic my-topic`

If you are not sure you can use the `dry-run` option before executing to check the output.

You can find [further documentation here.](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group)